# Prevent DirectX Fullscreen interruption.

Tags: .net, fullscreen, directx-11, sharpdx

I am using sharpdx's toolkit to make a fullscreen directx 11 window.

now whenever another application is opening a window this fullscreen gets lost. (e.g. popups from skype, error messages, ...)

i've seen that other games can avoid this somehow, so i was wondering if this is also possible with sharpdx toolkit and if so, how?

if it's not possible with the toolkit how can it be done with directx 11 functions?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an XNA application I created a while back.  I had some success using a Windows API PInvoke.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool LockSetForegroundWindow(uint uLockCode);
    public static readonly uint LSFW_LOCK = 1;
    public static readonly uint LSFW_UNLOCK = 2;
}

// Prevent annoying windows notifications etc from stealing focus and ruining the show!
NativeMethods.LockSetForegroundWindow(NativeMethods.LSFW_LOCK);
```